# How to verify completeness of save/load system

Tags: c#, reflection, code-analysis

I am making a save/load system for a big game project in C#.

Each class that has to be saved implements a method `DoSnapshot()`.

Inside the method, the programmer must make a call to a function for every field in the class - either `DoSnapshot(foo)` if `foo` should be saved, or `Ignore(foo)` if it should not.

I have a DoSnapshot method for many primitive types like DoFloat, DoString as well as versions for complex types.

I have 100s of classes and the project is still being developed.

Is it possible to add some kind of verification that all of the fields in each class are either used in a `Snapshot()` or an `Ignore()` call? Omitting fields would cause bugs.
The verification could either be runtime, or compile-time. I only want to use it during development, it will not be released to users.

Comment: Have you looked in writting a custom FXCop Rule? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: No... anyways, we are using Visual Studio Express 2010 and I don't think it is supported.

Comment: Nope it's not there are other tools that do Static Code analysis and let you add custom rules. I think your best bet is to provide a Base DoSnapshot method so the devs only have to mark with attributes...You can easily write a routine to make sure every object that needs saved has all properties marked as required or ignore. And the devs wouldn't have to implement the dosnapshot method:-)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an attribute to the fields that need to be saved, and then loop over every property in your class in the `DoSnapshot` method. When the property has the attribute you're looking for, you call `Snapshot`, otherwise you call `Ignore`.

```
public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }

    public override void DoSnapshot()
    {
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var isRequired = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (RequiredAttribute), false).Length > 0;
            if (isRequired)
            {
                // Something
            }
            else
            {
                // SomethingElse
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is to check if the programmer has forgotten something. Using tags instead of method calls seems to only move the problem...

Comment: In the example I provided, all the properties are fetched and either Ignore or Snapshot can be called, so you are insuring that every field is looked at.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Well there should be an Ignore tag also. 
In any case, what I need is verification for the method calls.
The example is simplified. I have about 30 versions of DoSnapshot - DoFloat, DoString etc.

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is create an attribute and "tag" each field if it should be saved or not. Then, at runtime, i would query the class using reflection to get all fields which should be serialized:

```
public class RandomClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class IgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var properties = typeof(RandomClass).GetProperties()
                        .Where(prop => !prop.IsDefined(typeof(IgnoreAttribute), false));
        // Serialize all values
    }
}
```